# ng-repeat not working while ng-view redirect to another page

Tags: angularjs

**while i am calling {{jeans.title}} in product page its not working.**

my app.js code:-

```
<!-- Modules -->

var app = angular.module('GalleryApp', ['ngRoute']);


<!-- routeProvider -->

app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', { 
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/products/:id', {
        controller: 'ProductsController',
        templateUrl:'views/product.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
});



<!-- Controllers -->

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'products', function($scope, products) {
    products.success(function(data1) {
        $scope.products = data1;

    });
}]);

app.controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', 'products', '$routeParams', function($scope, products, $routeParams) {
    products.success(function(data2) {
        jeans = data2[$routeParams.id];
    });

}]);


<!-- services -->

app.factory('products', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('products.json')
         .success(function(data) {
           return data;
         });
}]);
```

index.html:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Include the core AngularJS library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the AngularJS routing library -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="GalleryApp">

    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

home.html:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="men in products.mens">
      <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="jean in men.jeans">
        <p>{{ jean.title }}</p>
        <img ng-src="{{ jean.img }}" alt="{{ jean.brand }}" title="{{ jean.brand }}"/>
        <h3>{{ jean.brand }}</h3>
        <h4>{{ jean.model }}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

product.html:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>{{ jeans.title }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Product.json:-

```
{
  "mens": [
    {
      "name": "mens fasion",
      "jeans": [
        {
          "title": "Slim fit",
          "model": "slim 2527",
          "brand": "Tommy Hilfiger",
          "img": "images/mens/jeans/product_1.jpg",
          "price": "2000",
          "offer": "10"
        },
        {
          "title": "Parallel",
          "model": "Parallel-1575",
          "brand": "Denim",
          "img": "images/mens/jeans/product_2.jpg",
          "price": "2500",
          "offer": "15"
        },
        {
          "title": "cargos",
          "model": "cargos 2876",
          "brand": "Lee Cooper",
          "img": "images/mens/jeans/product_3.jpg",
          "price": "3000",
          "offer": "20"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

while i am calling {{jeans.title}} in product page its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ProductsController`

```
    jeans = data2[$routeParams.id];
```

you are missing `$scope.`. It should be:

```
    $scope.jeans = data2[$routeParams.id];
```

Also, it seems that you want to access the sub-object `mens[0].jeans` within your JSON object here:

```
    $scope.jeans = data2.mens[0].jeans[$routeParams.id];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Manikandan. Yes, as you said i'm trying to access sub-object mens.jeans within the JSON. But Still i'm facing the same issue.

I have given every bit of code. If possible can you share me a corrected version of code through Jsfiddle or some other online editors. so that it will be more useful for me.

Comment: @karthickravindranath If you share your non-working code via JSFiddle, I try to find other issues.

Comment: since i was unable to put every bit of my code. i have uploaded it to google drive. @leemes PFA of my query
[product query](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yTbYRxA0PRZW1pZFBydlBYamM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @karthickravindranath In line 34, you are still missing $scope. Also, line 40 doesn't make any sense. Since you push the data into your array using forEach, you don't need that line anymore. However, the line from my answer should do that just fine (no forEach needed)... Try to add `console.log($scope.jeans)` afterwards to see if it was set properly. It could be that it is set properly but that your UI isn't updating as expected.

Comment: i have used `products.success(function(data2) {
  $scope.jeans = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(mens) {
   angular.forEach(mens.jeans, function(jeans) {
    $scope.jeans.push(jeans)
   })
  })
  console.log($scope.jeans);
 });`

Comment: Have you tried this? `products.success(function(data2) {
        $scope.jeans = data2.mens.jeans[$routeParams.id];
    });`

Comment: And have you tried to print anything with `console.log`?

Comment: yes @leemes tried above one too. still i was unable to view my json data in the product page.

Comment: Hi @leemes i have created a link similar to JsFiddle. Please look into it. I hope by this link you can find me a solution for my issue.
when i click on details button it will redirect to product page. but the expression in it was not working properly.

[https://plnkr.co/edit/g0wNuC?p=info](https://plnkr.co/edit/g0wNuC?p=info)

Comment: Ah now I see it. `mens` is an array. I can't really understand your JSON file... However, you need to access the jeans correctly in your js code... Adding `[0]` after `mens` (that is: `data2.mens[0].jeans[$routeParams.id];`) should do the trick

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your patience in answering my question @leemes . Finally you found me the correct answer. Thanks you so much.